# pass through mechanism with fs2 Stream

Tags: scala, streaming, fs2

Would anyone know how to reproduce a pass through mechanism (as with Akka Stream) but with fs2 Stream ?

I would like to be able to split the values of on Object into 2 substreams, zipping them back together when the 2 substreams emit values.

One of the substreams would do nothing, only waiting for the other stream to emit a value and zip both values together.

```
case class Message(offset: Int, record: String)

Stream[Message] ->(offset goes here)Pipe[Int, Int]        -> (zip outputs)Pipe[Message, Message]
                -> (record goes here)Pipe[String, String]
```

Comment: `Pipe` doesn't guarantee one-to-one semantics, so what you want to do there doesn't make much sense. The whole thing is easier to do using just a simple `map` call.

Comment: Thing is I would like to use `through` but only with the record and still be able to get the associated offset after `through` call has ended

Comment: Why do you want to use `through`?

Comment: Because I want to hide all of the logic regarding the offset (reading it, commiting and so on) in a libray and only ask the users for a Pipe that describe the logic associated with the record.

Comment: Just ask the user for a function of `String => String` and use `map`, way simpler and actually guarantees that the function is one-to-one _(something pipe doesn't)_. Again, not sure why you are so fixated on using `pipe` to solve this problem.

Comment: Problem is when asking for a simple String => String, the user cannot use any Streaming functions such as delay, throttle, or fine tuning parallelism on certain logic blocks. Which is something my users need to be able to do.
I want them to be able to handle a Stream of records and not only a single record

Comment: You can often use `observe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly what you want to do doesn't make sense from the stream point of view.
First, you can't split a `Stream` into two independent ones since the life cycle of one depends on the life cycle of the other.
Second, if you expose the whole `Stream` to your users, then they would be able to call a lot of things that may increase or reduce the number of elements, thus you would lose the one-to-one semantics.

I can think of three *"solutions"* to your problem.

#### 1. Don't do it

I know, I know. This is not a solution *per se*, but is a valid option.
Take a look to libraries like [**fs2-kafka**](https://fd4s.github.io/fs2-kafka/docs/overview) they don't hide the off-set, rather they force their users to keep track of it.

#### 2. Create your own Stream projection

Create a custom class that internally contains a `Stream[Message]` but that exposes only one-to-one methods and hides the offset. Then you can ask for a function using that data type.

#### 3. Concurrency with Queues *(dangerous)*

The only way I know of splitting streams is by using `Queues` *(the **cats-effect** ones)*.

The idea is simple, first, you are going to use `evalMap` to send each offset into a `Queue` and then just project the message. Then, you can use `through` on that stream using the `Pipe` the user provided. Finally, you use another `evalMap` to retrieve the offset again from the `Queue`.

Again, this may lead to corruption if users break the one-to-one semantics.

---

Anyways, I would recommend also asking on the [**typelevel** **Discord** server](https://discord.gg/deUtQsP6), folks there may have a different / better advice.